# How to focus v-radio-group selected radio programmatically?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How to focus v-radio-group selected radio programmatically ?

```html
<v-radio-group v-model="radios" :mandatory="false" ref="RadioGroup">
  <v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1"></v-radio>
  <v-radio label="Radio 2" value="radio-2"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

I tried with `this.$refs.RadioGroup.focus()` but nothing happens.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Two things

- Vuetify adds divs and inputs to the DOM, so you need to dig in to the referenced element's children a little
- you probably want to target one of the radio buttons since focusing the group seems to have no effect

This works, so might give you a idea to work with

```html
<v-radio-group v-model="radios" :mandatory="false" ref="RadioGroup">
  <v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1" ref="Radio1"></v-radio>
  <v-radio label="Radio 2" value="radio-2" ref="Radio2"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

```js
this.$refs.Radio2[0].$el.children[0].children[0].focus()
```

Tested with this listener

```js
created() {
  document.addEventListener('focusin', event => {
    console.log('focused', event.target)
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html). Add 'radio-focus' as a directive to the Vue Instance Add the v-radio-focus directive as an attribute to the v-radio element you wish to focus on. More about directives [here](http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/directives.html).

```
 'radio-focus': {
      // directive definition
      inserted: function (el) {
          const $el: HTMLElement = el.children[0].children[0] as HTMLElement
          $el.focus()
        }
      }
```